# How can I dynamically change the condition of where, depending on the parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write it with a single query.
Depending on the parameter regionid must hold one of the conditions if the parameter is greater than zero regionid if this parameter is involved in the request if there is not involved.

```
 var myRegionId = 0;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(regionId))
                {
                    myRegionId = int.Parse(regionId);
                }

                IOrderedQueryable price;
                if (myRegionId>0)
                {
                     price = (from p in _db.PRICEs
                                  join good in _db.GOODs on p.good_id equals good.id
                                  join gname in _db.spr_goods_names on good.goods_name_id equals gname.id
                                  where ******p.region_id == myRegionId &&** gname.name.ToLower().Contains(filterText.ToLower())****
                                  group p by new{ p.good_id} into g
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      GoodId = g.Key.good_id,
                                      Promotion = g.Count(x => x.promotion != ""),
                                      MinPrice = g.Min(x => x.good_price),
                                      DistributorCount = g.Count(x => x.distributor_id != null)
                                  }
                            ).OrderByDescending(x => x.DistributorCount).Take(100).OrderBy(x => x.MinPrice);
                }else
                {
                    price = (from p in _db.PRICEs
                             join good in _db.GOODs on p.good_id equals good.id
                             join gname in _db.spr_goods_names on good.goods_name_id equals gname.id
                             **where gname.name.ToLower().Contains(filterText.ToLower())**
                             group p by new { p.good_id } into g
                             select new
                             {
                                 GoodId = g.Key.good_id,
                                 Promotion = g.Count(x => x.promotion != ""),
                                 MinPrice = g.Min(x => x.good_price),
                                 DistributorCount = g.Count(x => x.distributor_id != null)
                             }
                           ).OrderByDescending(x => x.DistributorCount).Take(100).OrderBy(x => x.MinPrice);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
 price = (from p in _db.PRICEs
          join good in _db.GOODs on p.good_id equals good.id
          join gname in _db.spr_goods_names on good.goods_name_id equals gname.id
          where (myRegionId <= 0 || p.region_id == myRegionId) && gname.name.ToLower().Contains(filterText.ToLower())
          group p by new{ p.good_id} into g
          select new
          {
              GoodId = g.Key.good_id,
              Promotion = g.Count(x => x.promotion != ""),
              MinPrice = g.Min(x => x.good_price),
              DistributorCount = g.Count(x => x.distributor_id != null)
          }).OrderByDescending(x => x.DistributorCount).Take(100).OrderBy(x => x.MinPrice);
```

if `myRegionId <= 0`, then it evaluates to `true` and `p.region_id == myRegionId` is not evaluated and thus ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Use lazy loading feature, as long as you don't need data, you can manipulate of query building.

```
var a = from p in _db.PRICEs
...

if (condition) a = a.where...
else a=a.where...

if (condition2) a = a.where...

var b = from a ....
```

Once you iterate foreach or call ToList data will be downloaded, and query promted to db. So before promting you can do what you need.

PS: Use profiler to check query send to BD for optimizing perfomance. Sometimes ORM can construct something very huge and hurt perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also split it up in parts, like so:

```
var query = from p in _db.PRICEs        
            join good in _db.GOODs on p.good_id equals good.id                                    
            join gname in _db.spr_goods_names on good.goods_name_id equals gname.id
            where gname.name.ToLower().Contains(filterText.ToLower())
            select p;

if (myRegionId>0)
{
   query = query.Where(p => p.region_id == myRegionId);
}

var price = from p in query
            group p by new{ p.good_id} into g
            select new
            {
               GoodId = g.Key.good_id,
               Promotion = g.Count(x => x.promotion != ""),
               MinPrice = g.Min(x => x.good_price),
               DistributorCount = g.Count(x => x.distributor_id != null)
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.DistributorCount).Take(100).OrderBy(x => x.MinPrice);
```